# Casting : lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, casting, compiler-errors, gpu, c99

I'm just using this code on a system without complete memory management :

```
typedef unsigned short component_t;
typedef struct {
    component_t* c;    // least-significant word first
    unsigned int num_components; // number of unsigned short rows
} integer;

integer result;
result.c=malloc(component_t*)malloc(sizeof(component_t)*128); //this is just an example to tell I'm correctly initializing. There's no malloc nor memset inside OpenCL. currently, I'm trying to speed up the code serially before switching to OpencL. That's also why I don't use GMP.
result.num_components=128
```

The next line:

```
for(int i=0;i<result.num_components/4;i++) (unsigned long)result.c[i] = 26; // assign 26 in that part of the memory
```

trigger:

```
gcc integer.c
integer.c:567:36 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     (unsigned long)result.c[5] = 26;
                                ^
```

I have no idea of the real problem with that line and what I need exactly to write for correcting this.
*Note :* I've also seen *(even if this is useless)* that :

```
for(int i=0;i<result.num_components/4;i++) (unsigned long)result.c[i]++
```

compiles while

```
for(int i=0;i<result.num_components/4;i++) (unsigned long)result.c[i]+=1
```

doesn't.

Comment: `result.c=malloc(component_t*)malloc(...`: Unfortunate copy/paste?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Just because you make compiler errors go away doesn't mean that the code is going to work :)

Comment: @user2284570: There's an extra `malloc` there. I don't see how that could possibly compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> integer.c:567:36 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
>      (unsigned long)result.c[5] = 26;
>                                 ^
> ```

The value of `result.c[5]` is retrieved and converted to `unsigned long`, which leaves you with an assignment similar to `15 = 26`. What you (presumably) want is to convert `result.c` to a **pointer** to `unsigned long`:

```
 ((unsigned long *)result.c)[5] = 26;
```